# Comparadores logicos en estructura condicional Switch Case

Tags: c++, lógica

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio practico en el que me piden que implemente la misma solución con if anidados y con switch.

El if anidado es sencillo:

```
int numero;
char tipo;

if (numero <= 10) { 
tipo = 'A';
} else if (numero > 10 && numero <= 20) { 
tipo = 'B';
}
```

Esto lo tengo muy claro, pero no entiendo de que manera se puede pasar esto a un switch, pues antes no he utilizado operadores lógicos en los **case**:

```
switch (numero) {
         case ??? :
              tipo = 'A';
              break;
}
```

Es la primera vez que me enfrento a esto, pues siempre que veía este problema utilizaba los if anidados...
La pregunta en sí es si se pueden manejar operadores lógicos en el switch, o si hay alguna otra manera que lo complemente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> antes no he utilizado operadores lógicos en los case:

Los `case` solo admiten **valores calculables en tiempo de compilación**, así que, aunque **si** puedas usar operadores en algunos casos, **no** podrás usarlos con variables.

El truco está en que el *cuerpo* del `case` **puede estar vacío**:

```
#include <iostream>

void function( int value ) {
  switch( value ) {
  case 10:
  case 11:
  case 12:
  case 13:
  case 14:
  case 15:
  case 16:
  case 17:
  case 18:
  case 19:
  case 20:
    std::cout << "10 <= " << value << " <= 20 \n";
    return;
  }

  // Si en el switch anterior ya comprobamos si estaba entre 10 y 20.
  // Pr lógica, si ahora no es < 10 es porque es > 20.
  switch( value < 10 ) {
  case 1:
    std::cout << value << " < 10\n";
    break;

  default:
    std::cout << value << " > 20\n"; 
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  function( 1 );
  function( 10 );
  function( 15 );
  function( 20 );
  function( 25 );

  return 0;
}
```

Que da como resultado:

> 1 < 10
> 10 <= 10 <= 20
> 10 <= 15 <= 20
> 10 <= 20 <= 20
> 25 > 20

Si el rango a considerar fuerea mas amplio, de forma que no sea factible usar tantos `case` vacíos, siempre podemos jugar con `switch( )` simples, situando adecuadamente los `return`:

```
void function( int value ) {
  static constexpr int MINIMO = 1000;
  static constexpr int MAXIMO = 5000;

  switch( value < MINIMO ) {
  case 1:
    std::cout << value << " < " << MINIMO << '\n';
    return;
  }

  switch( value > MAXIMO ) {
  case 1:
    std::cout << value << " > " << MAXIMO << '\n';
    break;

  default:
    std::cout << MINIMO << " <= " << value << " <= " << MAXIMO<< '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta me parece dinámica y aceptable, pero habría un inconveniente si el rango de números fuera más alto, pues se tendrían que escribir uno por uno todos los case del rango. Ej = entre 1 y 1000

Comment: @JuanPabloCortesMoncada No tiene porqué. Observa el segundo `switch( )`. Con el emulamos un `if - else` tradicional. Es cosa de jugar con `switch( )` como ese y situar correctamente los `return`.

Comment: @JuanPabloCortesMoncada Respuesta editada con un ejemplo. **No lo he probado** pero, salvo cambios mínimos, debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

En un switch no se pueden usar operadores relacionales para estos caso es mejor usar las sentencias if-else

La respuesta a tu pregunta es que eso no se puede hacer

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes Juan Pablo, debes tener presente que en los Switch no se usa los operadores de comparación `<`, `>=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, etc. el Switch solo acepta valores positivos, a diferencia de los condicionales `IF...ELSE IF`, etc. ¿Cuando usar uno u otro?...

Si en tu situacion debes condicionar y comparar situaciones, con los operadores descritos anteriormente, entonces debes usar un `IF` acompañado de `ELSE IF` si quizás tu codigo lo requiere, pero si quizas tienes una situación como la que planteo a continuación:

SITUACIÓN:
Vamos a suponer que el cliente va a elegir un numero de una lista de items, y para cada item el codigo debe realizar una accion o conjunto de acciones diferentes.

Podrías usar IF:

```
if (variable == 1)
{
    .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
}elseif (variable == 2)
{
    .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
}elseif (variable == 3)
{
    .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
}elseif (variable == 4)
{
    .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
}elseif (variable == 5)
{
    .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
}else
{
    .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
}
```

Pero si notas solo estas evaluando si un valor es igual a... Estas usando solo el operador de comparación "==", pues entonces en este caso sería mas práctico usar un Switch de la siguiente manera.

```
Switch (variable)
{
    case 1:
        .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
        break;
    case 2:
        .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
        break;
    case 3:
        .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
        break;
    case 4:
        .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
        break;
    case 5:
        .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
        break;
    default:
        .... Sentencias de código a ejecutar;
        break;
}
```

Notar que estás haciendo la misma operación de comparar pero de una manera más práctica.

CONCLUSIÓN:
Si tu ejercicio solo vas a evaluar condiciones con el operador "==", entonces puedes usar un Switch, de lo contrario deberías usar un IF solo o de manera anidada.

Espero haberte podido ayudar.

Answer (score -1):

Los bloques de código etiquetados con case pueden estar acompañados de cualquier expresión y el valor al cual se evalué va a ser la que se va a comparar con el otro valor que tienes en `switch()`

```
if (numero <= 10) { 
tipo = 'A';
} else if (numero > 10 && numero <= 20) { 
tipo = 'B';
}
```

Esto pasado a un switch:

```
    switch(numero){
      case 2+2:{
       break;
      }
      case numero > 10 && numero <= 20:{
        break;
      } 
      case numero <= 10:{
       break;
      }
    }

}
```

TL;DR
switch es igual que un if solo que la expresión la pones en los cases jeje

Comment: ¿ Has intentado compilar tu código ? ¿ Estás seguro de que eso funciona ?

Comment: Antes de publicar nada, pruebalo. Te evitaras bochornos publicando errores. Mejor elimina tu respuesta para no inducir a otros a errar.

Comment: *switch es igual que un if solo que la expresión la pones en los cases jeje* El `switch` solo soporta valores integrales (enteros, carácteres, enums), el `if` soporta cualquier expresión que se traduzca a un valor booleano.